# Did the Dark Lord attempt to free any patients from St Mungo's Hospital?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, death-eaters

Did the Dark Lord attempt or succeed to free any crazy patients from St Mungo's Hospital for Magical Maladies and Injuries or just from Azkaban?

Comment: Why do you think he'd want to? I mean, what benefit would crazy patients have to Voldemort? (Not shooting you down, really asking :-) )

Comment: I assumed you meant to act as like berserker troops? If that was what you had in mind, I'm sure he'd have his skilled and reasonably intelligent (well, some of them) Death Eaters or his army of Inferi for the less-controlled style of attack. No mad men needed.

Comment: @MacCooper I suppose I was wondering if some of them were still useful to him.  I agree nobody was ever mentioned that he may be interested in using but would be interesting if there was.  Perhaps like a truly mad soldier that was so mad they would be unyielding.

Comment: @ThruGog correct thats what I was thinking.  You're right, I guess I wasn't thinking about the fact that they would be quite useless.  He did tend to have plenty of skilled and intelligent help.  I suppose I was really just wondering if there were any patients that were more on the lines of criminally insane that he could make use of.  I do think the idea is interesting having escaped mental patients being reckless and having their wands to do god knows what with.

Comment: @JoshBreakingNews why would he need to break into a hospital to get a crazy follower? He's got Bellatrix for that! Haha ;) but actually this is an interesting question you got my vote

Comment: @MacCooper You're a Mudblood, aren't you?! :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Unknown, but I’d guess not.**

To the best of my knowledge, the only Death Eater attack on St. Mungo’s came in *Order of the Phoenix*, when a piece of Devil’s Snare was smuggled into the building to kill Broderick Bode, who knew the truth about the Department of Mysteries. There’s nothing to suggest an attack or attempt to free the patients.

---

I don’t think Voldemort would want to free any patients.

- He doesn’t care about his Death Eaters; instead he sees them as disposable pawns in his grand plan for immortality. If they’re stuck in St. Mungo’s, sucks for them.

  Who else would he be interested in breaking out?

  (Azkaban has a high concentration of Death Eaters, which makes it a much more valuable target. St. Mungo’s will only have a handful at any one time.)
- He’s doing a pretty good job winning the war without the patients on his side. Any patients will have some sort of injury, and for many that would affect their ability to do Death Eater work. You specifically ask about “crazy patients” – I assume you mean people like Lockhart or the Longbottoms, who are long-term residents with severe mental health problems. Anybody like that is almost certainly without a wand.

  Basically, the patients of St. Mungo’s are of limited value.
- He’s interested in immortal life. Although he has that through his horcruxes, he probably still needs medical knowledge. No good living forever if your body is broken down and riddled with disease. St. Mungo’s is a concentration of useful medical knowledge.

  Attacking the hospital, or breaking out the patients, could cause the Healers to scatter. If he doesn’t need to do so, he’d probably rather keep them together in one place. That makes them easier to round up after the war is won.

Comment: +1 I couldn't remember when Broderick was attacked. Good answer as always Alex.

Comment: For your last point, I have a hard time believing that Voldemort would a) admit weakness to the point of needing a doctor, or b) trust a strange doctor to minister to him. At "best", he'd probably kill the doctor right after receiving whatever services he required. I don't think that having a hospital available as a resource -- except maybe if it had a library or artifacts he could use/appropriate -- would be a significant factor.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I didn’t think Voldemort would use their services directly, but probably take their knowledge of medicine.

Comment: Brilliant answer as usual @alexwlchan.  I totally agree and had a few Duh moments, like of course they would be wandless and  more often than not a burden.  Also I do believe he would not want to scatter the healers or lead to the closing of the Hospital.  Like perhaps he may want to lock some people up there that he for some reason kept alive but disagreed with.  I guess with this question I was mostly thinking that there were some useful(to him) crazy death eaters or something in Hospital.

Answer (score 4):

I would say No, based on there being no mention of any breakouts in the books or on Pottermore.

Also there are never mentions of "Criminally Insane" in the HP series, mostly it seems that criminals are sent to Azkaban and then become insane or at least a bit more psychotic mass murdery.

It's obvious that it wasn't an issue to break into the place considering he broke into Azkaban and later on he had Ministry Control and could have easily released them through official routes.

Comment: Absolutely, I agree it would not have been an issue since he did it at Azkaban. You very much answered my question saying there was no mention of any criminally insane in the series.  Thats more less what I was imagining.  Sort of straight jacket wizards stuck in padded rooms that would follow the Dark Lord.  There were definitely similar ideas but I suppose no one in St. Mungo's would have been much use to The Dark Lord.

Comment: Yes it would seem anyone potentially dangerous from the first reign was just locked up in Azkaban. They tend to go insane there anyway so why would they bothered keeping them at St Mungo's?

Answer (score 0):

## It’s unlikely - Death Eaters were sent to Azkaban, not St. Mungo’s.

The Dark Lord planned to break into Azkaban because his devoted followers were locked away there, and he intended to free them from inside it so they could rejoin him.

> “They went to Azkaban rather than renounce me … when Azkaban is broken open, the Lestranges will be honoured beyond their dreams. The Dementors will join us … they are our natural allies … we will recall the banished giants … I shall have all my devoted servants returned to me, and an army of creatures whom all fear …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

He mentions nothing about any Death Eater being absent from the graveyard because they were sent to St. Mungo’s, and there likely aren’t any who were - Death Eaters all seem to be sent to Azkaban instead. Even the ‘craziest’ Death Eaters were likely locked up in Azkaban, since there doesn’t seem to be any ‘insanity defense’ in the wizarding world’s courts.